# Using the file_get_contents function, I want to get first few google results, instead of all

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I've used the file_get_contents to get the google results of a string and display to the web page.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=".$str;

$result = file_get_contents($url);

echo $result;
```

But is it possible to display only the first few results, say 5, instead of all the results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit the number of Google search results, add the parameter `&num=5` to your Google query.

Compare

https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=foo

https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=foo&num=5